# jQuery AJAX callback not executed when debugging via Firebug

Tags: jquery, debugging, asynchronous, firebug

This is a frequently observed behavior. jQuery asynchronous AJAX calls work flawlessly while running without opening Firebug. However, when Firebug is opened and I am debugging by putting some breakpoints in some other part of the code, the AJAX callback event doesn't fire.

My assumption is that, since I am already debugging step-by-step in another unrelated part of code, the AJAX response callback event is getting *escaped*. Is this assumption right?  If yes, how do I ensure that callback fires always? If not, what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> My assumption is that, since I am already debugging step-by-step in
>   another unrelated part of code, the ajax response callback event is
>   getting escaped. Is this assumption right?

Yes, in Firebug 1.x. Though that's [fixed](http://code.google.com/p/fbug/issues/detail?id=6205) in Firebug 2.0 (at the time of writing this answer in beta phase).

E.g. check out the following code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function makeRequest()
{
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open("GET", "test.php");

    xhr.onreadystatechange = function()
    {
        if (xhr.readyState === XMLHttpRequest.DONE)
            console.log("Request finished");
    }

    xhr.send(null);
    debugger;
}
</script>
<button onclick="makeRequest()">Make request</button>
```

When you click the *Make request* button you'd expect `Request finished` to be logged to the console.
In Firebug up to 1.12.8 the output doesn't appear in the console, while it does in 2.0.
This is because Firebug 2.0 [adapts new debugger APIs](https://blog.getfirebug.com/2014/03/26/firebug-2-0-alpha-1/) exposed by Firefox, which fixed this problem.

Though note that the asynchronous call to `onreadystatechange` will not be deferred. That means it will still be executed even when you're stopped at the `debugger` keyword. So a breakpoint at `console.log("Request finished")` will **not** be hit.

This is a difference to the JavaScript engines of Chrome, Opera and Internet Explorer, where the execution of asynchronous functions is waiting for the debugger to continue the script execution.

Comment: I agree that a breakpoint at console.log(...) above shdn't be hit.  But I hope the new debugger will print the console.log nevertheless.  I mean the behavior of the system in terms of ajax responses shouldn't be different when I am running in debug mode and normal mode.

Comment: You can try out Firebug 2.0. Just [download the latest beta version from addons.mozilla.org](https://addons.mozilla.org/firefox/addon/firebug/#beta-channel). Though note that it requires at least Firefox 30, which is currently available as [Aurora version](https://www.mozilla.org/firefox/aurora/).